# It's possible put a fragment into a swipe tabs?

Tags: android, layout, tabs, fragment

I have one swipe tab with 3 fragments. In the first fragment I want to put two fragment, one fragment for information and one for login operation. I'll ask you if it's possible doing it and with how API it's possible this. I've searched in the web information but I don't understand so much. If it's possible, I need an example.
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean a swipe tabs inside a fragment?

Comment: Yes possible, suggest using nested fragments in first fragment